# Media Query for small device size not working when viewing in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

help my media query doesn't work in chrome why?

Should turn background purple when i make the browser with small. I pulled this example from w3 schools so i know it should work. by default the small size is purple no media query set and if it reaches a certain width size it should change to blue.

```css
body { background-color: purple; }

.wrapper {overflow: auto;}
#main {margin-left: 4px;}
#leftsidebar {
  float: none;
  width: auto;
}
#menulist {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menuitem {
  background: #CDF0F6;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #leftsidebar {width: 200px; float: left;}
  #main {margin-left: 216px;}
  body{background-color: blue;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="leftsidebar">
    <ul id="menulist">
      <li class="menuitem">Menu-item 1</li>
      <li class="menuitem">Menu-item 2</li>
      <li class="menuitem">Menu-item 3</li>
      <li class="menuitem">Menu-item 4</li>
      <li class="menuitem">Menu-item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>     
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
    <p>This example shows a menu that will float to the left of the page if the viewport is 480 pixels wide or wider. If the viewport is less than 480 pixels, the menu will be on top of the content.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have some more info, when I just checked in CodePen it seams fine.
https://codepen.io/bratorimatori/pen/wvvrVLp

Comment: Seems to work...

Comment: it will work in code pen but not in the actual chrome browser.

Comment: I ran it locally and it worked. Maybe 480px is smaller than you think. Try upping that value and test again or have the developer tools open to know the width of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the pixel rate and see if you have actually hit the media query boundaries. Best to to open a console, in Chrome on the upper right corner you will see the current resolution.